# Is there an event that will tell me when a textarea's selection/cursor position changes?

Tags: javascript, dom, textarea

I'm using the `selectionStart`, `selectionEnd`, and `selectionPosition` properties for a textarea I'm manipulating, but I need an event that will tell me when these values change?

I found the [document selectionchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event), but that's not quite what I want. It fires on the document directly and does so when any selection in the document changes (too much). I want something scoped to the textarea.

Does such an event exist?

If it doesn't, I'll be forced to use either the document's selectionchange event or a combination of keyup/mouseup on the textarea with some extra conditions to make sure it actually changed.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you cannot fire a selection change event on the element, so we will need to add to the document.

The selection is only ever happening once at a given time, so really no issue listening to it and filtering as needed. Remember all events on elements are propagating up to `document` anyway, we just not listening to them all.

Added a snippet to demo.

**Snippet:**

```js
const target = document.querySelector('#content');

document.addEventListener('selectionchange', checkSelection);

function checkSelection(e) {
  if(document.activeElement !== target) {
    return;
  }
  
  console.log(document.getSelection().toString());
}
```

```html
<textarea id="content">
  How do I check where the cursor is?
</textarea>

<textarea id="notme">
  Not this content please
</textarea>
```

Comment: I don't want it to run on every click event. Also, this doesn't handle the case where the user changes the cursor position/selection with the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can track onKeyDown event inside your input and run it for every time the event is fired